# CStringArray MFC serialization on 32bit and deserialization on 64 bit

Tags: serialization, mfc, 32bit-64bit, porting

I'm struggling a lot porting an MFC application from 32bit to 64bit.
I have same classes with `CStringArray` members and they use the `CArchive` serialization and all works fine in 32 bit app.

Now I split the same application into two parts, one in 32bit and the other in 64 bit and they need to share some serialized data; when I serialize a `CStringArray` member and try to deserialize it in the 64 bit app I get an `CArchiveException`, with cause=3 that should be "`endOfFile`".

It's not clear what's going on, I suspect that I can't serialize it a data in 32 bit and read it on 64 bit app due to the size. If I follow the `GetSize()` function of `CStringArray`, I see that the return is `INT_PTR` that is defined as follows:

[image: Defined of INT_PTR]

This means there is no way to make a `CStringArray` serialization on 32bit and deserialization on 64 bit? Exist an workaround or something similar? There are other MFC data that I should check between 32 and 64 app?

EDIT: The problem is not related strictly on the CStringArray that (see the comments) is fine between 32/64.

Comment: That can be valid for the size, but the size is not serialize...I made a empty project and tried to serialize a CStringArray at 32 bit and read it on 64 and viceversa and all works.. maybe it's another type or a different problem..

Comment: OK. The `m_size` member *is* serialized but it uses the `CArchive` class `WriteCount` and `ReadCount` routines, which (sort of) take care of the 32/64 bit size issue.

Comment: Yes infact I start thinking that it's not about the CStringArray maybe. In my demo program I have tried many data types, and also a CObject, but in the demo works ever, not in the main app that are the same data types, also more then a couple... there is a way to understand how many byte are readed in the serialize for each variables?

Comment: `CStringArray` serializes absolutely fine and can be read / written to between both bit builds. What I found to be the issue is the numeric fields. You have to choose variable types that don't change between the two bit editions. E.g., use `WORD` or `DWORD`. If you use `int` then it takes a different amount of data per bit build and throws it all out.

Comment: 'int' should not change because the 64bit use the LLP64 sistem and the int in 32 bit long in both. What changes are the size of the pointer but I can't find what is the problem.

Comment: Why people are using `CStringArray` things nowadays? That thing is very obsolete. Even a `CString<CArray>` is. Unless you have very old legacy code, or another very strong to user these jurassic era stuff, you should scrap it all and use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @sergiol As you can image, I have very old legacy code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my question for future readers. The problem was not related to the CStringArray but to other parts of code near it. The problem was that before CStringArray obj there is another member that was an CArray of a custom struct. This struct have a couple of members that use an override of the `CArchive SerializeElements` function to made a correct data serialization in 32 bit.

This serialize element was written in this way:

```
template<class TYPE> void AFXAPI SerializeElements (CArchive& ar, CRect* pElements, int nCount);
```

but the 64bit version does not use this override because the last parameter was `int` instead of `INT_PTR` and without using SerializeElements, I made a wrong serialization (less byte that needed, this is why I reach the endOfFile to soon while reading).

To fix it, just use the right declaration for the SerializeElements that is:

```
template<class TYPE> void AFXAPI SerializeElements (CArchive& ar, CRect* pElements, **INT_PTR** nCount);
```

Notice <s>int</s> => **INT_PTR**.

I hope it can help.